# Issues with the shape keys after fbx export

Tags: export, unity, shape-keys, .fbx

I create characters in Character Creator 3 and then export to Blender and then export for Unity (fbx).

I'm having an issue with shape keys on one of the characters I've been working on. The shape keys are incorrect after exporting from Blender to fbx.

When exporting from Blender all of the keys are set to 0 however once exported to fbx the lips seem to be in a different position (as if some of the keys were changed, however they all are still set to 0 in Unity).

[image]
[image]

(left: before exporting from Blender, expected lips shape, right: after exporting from Blender, lips are thin and squeezed)

After export, if I change any of the shape keys eg. the blink shape key value in Unity, the lips move as well, this does not happen in Blender.

[image]
[image]

(left: incorrect lips on the face with eyes open, right: blinking cause the lips to move as well)

Things I've tried so far:

- exporting straight from CC3 to Unity - no issues with shape keys
- checked all of the shape keys in Blender to ensure none of them causes this issue - all shape keys behave as expected
- reexporting from CC3 to Blender - the issue still occurs

I'll be really grateful for any guidance or pointing me to any similar issues.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to set all shape keys to default before export?

Comment: @Crantisz I've just tried that, unfortunately no difference

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having similar issue - I had a random Shape Key selected in the Edit mode.

To solve the issue:

- in Object mode select the object with shape keys
- go to Edit mode
- in the tab Object Data Properties -> Shape Keys, click on the element you want to be the default one

In my case, I clicked on the first key in the Shape Keys list. Once I clicked on 'Basis' and exported the model, the face and shape keys were correct

[image]